# Autofill macro to autofill dates up to 31 days regardless of the month

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

We have a job at hand where we have to format the given data into more useful lists. The problem is that this job will be repeated many times every month. So, when a macro is created the necessary dates should adapt to all months. For adaptation, it is not necessary for them to be specific. What I mean by that is, all months can end in the 31st day regardless of the month because then we can just leave those cells empty. For example; February 2023 ends in 28th day, however since the most days a month can have is 31 we want that as the last day so the autofill will end in 31.02.2023. Then, we can just leave the 29th, 30th, and 31st day empty.

Another thing, before starting the macro we want to specify the month and year to get the necessary dates. I have thought about manual input like "01.mm.yyyy" and the macro will use that cell as a reference for autofill. But I also want to know if we can use the Ctrl+Shift+; (semi-colon) shortcut to insert the current date so we wouldn't need to wait for an manual input. However, the problem with this is, for example, that  the current date may start from the 3rd day and the autofill will continue as 3rd, 4th, 5th, etc.

I have tried typing "01.02.2023" in a cell. Then I recorded a macro where I pulled it down so it would autofill all the days of that month. However, like I mentioned, it ended in the 28th day. Then, I autofilled up to the 28th day (because it is the lowest number of days a month can have, which can be filled with autofill no problem). Then I tried to use the input cell as the reference for the month and year, and as for the 29th, 30th, and 31st tried something like "29.mm(of the input cell).yyyy(of the input cell", "30.mm(of the input cell).yyyy(of the input cell)", and "31.mm(of the input cell).yyyy(of the input cell)". But I couldn't manage to get it working.

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: It is 2019, but would it be the same for 2016 and above?

Comment: I just edited my answer after re-reading your question where you wanted to specify Year and Month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2016+ with dynamic arrays, and you want to use a single formula, **AND** you are defining the Month and Year to use, then simply:

```
A1: =TEXT(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,31)),"00\.") & TEXT(Mnth,"00\.") & Yr
```

With `Yr` = `2023` and `Mnth` = `2`

[image]

To produce this using VBA, try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub MonthDays()
    Dim Yr As Long, y As String
    Dim Mnth As Long, m As String
    Dim vDates(1 To 31, 1 To 1) As Variant
    Dim I As Long
    Dim WS As Worksheet, rDest As Range
    
 Yr = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the Year as 'yyyy'", Title:="Year Input", Default:=Year(Date), Type:=1)
 Mnth = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the Month as 'm'", Title:="Month Input", Type:=1)
 
 y = Format(Yr, "0000")
 m = Format(Mnth, "00\.")
 
 'Create array with the date strings
 For I = 1 To 31
    vDates(I, 1) = Format(I, "00\.") & m & y
 Next I
 
 'write to the worksheet
 'below example shows one method
 Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With WS
    Set rDest = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(31, 1))
End With

With rDest
    .ClearContents
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = vDates
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One last thing, how can I integrate this into my macro? I assume I would have to type it in VBA format. Rather, would I be able to type for example; 01.05.2024 and start my macro and it would autofill up to 31.05.2024? Or, would I need to specify the month and year inside the function itself?

Comment: @Kalamakra What macro? You never showed any macro in your question.  Why do you need a macro when you can just use a worksheet formula?

Comment: This is just a part of the job that we are doing. The macro just rearranges and lists personel info for the specific dates. What I actually want is for the macro to create a new sheet, insert the current date in "01.mm.yyyy" format starting from B2, and make it autofill up to "31.mm.yyyy". Then, I would have it looped let's say 200 times. As a result, I would have the same date list from your figure from day 1 to 31 at a specific month and year looped 200 times starting from B2. I just needed to figure out a way to do "01.mm.yyyy" to "31.mm.yyyy" with macro.

Comment: In other words, I needed in VBA format for macro integration. This is why I would like to see if Ctrl+Shift+; (insert current date) could be integrated. But unfortunately I couldn't make what I had in mind work.

Comment: @Kalamakra I have added a VBA method. So far as integrating it into your macro, you will need to do that yourself. There is no way I can integrate into an unknown macro.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I can integrate it.